# Unreachable code detected in function

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am getting an "Unreachable Code Detected" error when running VS. I am getting the error at these two lines :

`MoveListItems(listBox1,listBox2)` and `ReplaceListItems(listBox1,listBox2)`

Any help is appreciated!

Code Below:

```
    private string CreateNewEntry(string current)
    {
        var indexIn = current.LastIndexOf("Time In : "); // Get the last index of the word "in"
        var indexOut = current.LastIndexOf("Time Out : "); // Get the last index of the word out

        if (indexOut > indexIn)
        {
            return current + "      "+"Time In : "; // if the last "out" comes after the last "in"
            ReplaceListBoxItems(listBox1,listBox2);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the last "in" comes after the last "out"
            return current + "      " +"Time Out : ";
            MoveListBoxItems(listBox1,listBox2);
        }
    }

    private void MoveListBoxItems(ListBox source, ListBox destination)
    {
        ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection sourceItems = source.SelectedItems;
        foreach (var item in sourceItems)
        {
            destination.Items.Add(item);
        }
        while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            source.Items.Remove(source.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are returning before hitting that part of the code.

Comment: You have `return` before those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have code after `return`-statements. That code will never be reached, as the return exits the method.

Consider moving `ReplaceListBoxItems(listBox1,listBox2);` above `return`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you use the `return` keyword before those lines. This style may be helpful

```
ReplaceListBoxItems(listBox1,listBox2);
return current + "      "+"Time In : "; // if the last "out" comes after the last "in"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace following lines instead of

```
         if (indexOut > indexIn)
          {
            ReplaceListBoxItems(listBox1,listBox2);
            return current + "      "+"Time In : ";// if the last "out" comes after the last "in"
          }
          else
          {
                // If the last "in" comes after the last "out"
                MoveListBoxItems(listBox1,listBox2);
                return current + "      " +"Time Out : ";
          }
```